# SVG.net does not read the file in svg format

Tags: c#, svg

Iam using this [library](https://svg.codeplex.com/) for convert the file .svg to image, Iam using the next code:

```
SvgDocument doc = GetSvgDocument(filePath);
doc.Draw().Save(@"C:\Users\710rent\Documents\elbueno.jpg");
```

shows error:

```
    System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=System.Drawing
  StackTrace:
       at System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath.AddString(String s, FontFamily family, Int32 style, Single emSize, PointF origin, StringFormat format)
       at Svg.SvgText.MeasureString(SvgRenderer renderer, String text, Font font)
       at Svg.SvgText.get_Path()
       at Svg.SvgGraphicsElement.Render(SvgRenderer renderer)
       at Svg.SvgText.Render(SvgRenderer renderer)
       at Svg.SvgElement.RenderChildren(SvgRenderer renderer)
       at Svg.SvgGroup.Render(SvgRenderer renderer)
       at Svg.SvgElement.RenderChildren(SvgRenderer renderer)
       at Svg.SvgElement.Render(SvgRenderer renderer)
       at Svg.SvgDocument.Draw()
       at Gaia.Models.iTextPdf.GetImageFromSVG(String filePath) in c:\vault\Gaia2016\Gaia\Gaia\Models\iTextPdf.cs:line 729
       at Gaia.Models.iTextPdf.Imprimir(String arrTitle, String arrEncabezado, Object[] arrResgitros, String imgLogo, String imgGraph, String group) in c:\vault\Gaia2016\Gaia\Gaia\Models\iTextPdf.cs:line 87
       at Gaia.Models.Reporte_anio_meses.Imprimir(String arrTitle, String arrEncabezado, String imgLogo, String imgGraph, String group) in c:\vault\Gaia2016\Gaia\Gaia\Models\Reporte_anio_meses.cs:line 348
       at Gaia.Controllers.AniosMesesController.Imprimir(String arrTitle, String arrEncabezado, String imgLogo, String imgGraph, String group) in c:\vault\Gaia2016\Gaia\Gaia\Controllers\AniosMesesController.cs:line 36
       at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  InnerException:
```

But with [this file](http://blackicemedia.com/presentations/2013-02-hires/img/awesome_tiger.svg) it works fine.

Comment: Can you post the sample SVG that you try ? Is there an empty text element in it ? Or maybe the the Font is not set properly ?

Comment: [https://filesharing24.com/d/Akj ] This is the file I'm working with.
When I compared the xml I find differences

Comment: Try removing the empty `text` tags. `<text... />` is not ok, `<text...>xyz</text>` is ok.